# What is a recommended way by Microsoft to achieve column audience targeting both in views and edit form section in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

I am new to sharepoint 2013 and exploring compatibility of its features with our requirement.

in effort of making complaint management system using sharepoint 2013.

I made form as

> Name
>
> Address
>
> Tel
>
> Problem Category
>
> Problem Description
>
> Assigned To
>
> Priority
>
> Due Date

what i want is that

everyone to be able to insert,update following feilds of form

> Name,Address,Tel,Problem Category, Problem Description

and only Head should be able to update following feilds

> Assigned To, Priority, Due Date

What i found till now is that

1. There is no column level permissions in sharepoint 2013.
2. Sharepoint Dessigner can be used to hide/delete form but thats not a secure     way to accomplish it. as any intelligent user can manipulate those form feilds.
3. I explored workflows, seems achievable by splitting form in stages, but i was unable to find any example of that type.
4. Work around could be to split form in two webparts on same page and use audience targeting, but was unable to find "edit list" webpart in ADD WEBPART section.

So in short my question is, what is a recommended way by microsoft to achieve column audience targetting both in views and edit form section?? i would love to achieve this by using workflows but how?